# Microsoft Azure Event Hub Kafka version

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

We are using Microsoft azure Event Hubs endpoints as Kafka cluster.

I want to know which version of Kafka is supported on Azure.

Which version of Kafka clients (producer and consumer) should be used to interact with Event Hubs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we are using microsoft azure event hub endpoints as kafka cluster

Azure EventHub is *not* Apache Kafka. It merely supports its users to leverage Kafka clients API for interacting with it. Though there are conceptual similarities between the two, EventHub should not be considered as a "Managed Kafka service" like HDInsight.

> I want to know which version of kafka is supported on azure ?

By Kafka, here kafka-clients should be meant. From the [Event Hubs documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-for-kafka-ecosystem-overview)..

> Event Hubs supports Apache Kafka's producer and consumer APIs clients
> at version 1.0 and above.

So, you can use Kafka clients 1.0 and above. Try using Kafka-clients 2.x.

You can go through the [sample code (Java)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-for-kafka/tree/master/tutorials/oauth/java/managedidentity) and [other languages](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-for-kafka/tree/master/tutorials/oauth) in Github here for interacting with EventHub through Kafka clients.